# How to pass string varible/argument in to mysql using RMYSQL

Tags: mysql, rmysql

I have a string variable called time which holds the time value like:

```
time = "2015.03.04";
```

I would like to pass this variable into mysql to retrieve information

```
 rs <- dbSendQuery(mydb, "SELECT * FROM TIMETABLE WHERE Time LIKE",time," 13:30%");
```

Now it prints the below error:

```
Error in mysqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  unused arguments ("2015.03.04", " 13:30%")
```

and now this is what I have got so far

```
sqlStatement <- paste("SELECT * FROM TIMETABLE WHERE Time LIKE '",time," 13:30%'")
sqlStatement
```

Result is:

```
> sqlStatement
[1] "SELECT * FROM TIMETABLE WHERE Time LIKE ' 2015.03.04  13:30%'"
```

I'm not able to get rid of the white space between `'` and 2015

Comment: Maybe you should remove `%` character at the end of your query? `13:30%");`

Comment: I need the % for matching,even i remove it it still prints me the same error without the% @_@, thanks for the response anyways:) keep on waiting for the answer

Comment: And what about whitespace after `LIKE`? If you concat that you will get string `LIKE2015.03.04` that likely will not parse correctly

Answer (score 1):

guess i would like to answer this myself, thanks for all the help!

my solution seems bit dumb, but solved the problem:)

```
time ="'2015.03.05";
sqlStatement <- paste("SELECT * FROM TIMETABLE WHERE Time LIKE ",time,"13:30%'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by paste(). You just need to set the "sep" parameter to an empty string because the default is a space. To use your example:

```
sqlStatement <- paste("SELECT * FROM TIMETABLE WHERE Time LIKE '",time," 13:30%'", sep="")
```

[paste documentation is here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/paste.html).

Happy querying!